# Flashdevelop Can't publish

Tags: ios, air, flashdevelop

My ios app is not publishing correctly after I have updated my AIR SDK to the AIR15 version. I had to update the SDK to add support for iOS8 and the new iPhones. The only clue is this error code when I publish the app:

Instruction does not dominate all uses!
  %EmptyStr = call %"avmplus::String"* @llGetString(%"avmplus::PoolObject"* %poo
l, i32 0)
  %EmptyStr_cast5 = getelementptr inbounds %"avmplus::String"* %EmptyStr, i32 0,
 i32 0, i32 0
Broken module found, compilation aborted!
Compilation failed while executing : compile-abc

Package setup creation FAILED.

Any help is appreciated or at least a direction to move in.

Answer (score 0):

We encountered this error on one of our own applications, and after quite a bit of research we discovered that it was this piece of code:

```
try
{
    var descriptor:XML = NativeApplication.nativeApplication.applicationDescriptor;
    var ns:Namespace = descriptor.namespace();
    version = "v" + descriptor.ns::versionNumber[0].toString();
}
catch (e:Error)
{
    version = "";
}
```

Removing the try/catch fixed the iOS compilation error.